# Does tomcat wait for application threads to complete before shutdown?

Tags: tomcat

When we shutdown tomcat using shutdown.sh script, does it wait for application threads to complete or does it kill them and shuts down tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat tries to kill application threads but if fails then error message like the one below might show up in the logs:

> SEVERE: The web application  appears to have started a thread
>   named [eg. ThreadExecutor_123] but has failed to stop it. This is
>   very likely to create a memory leak.`

After that Tomcat shuts down and leaves the application still running. To avoid this your thread should implement `ServletContextListener` and during Tomcat shut down you can stop your thread safely in `contextDestroyed` method. You can read more about `ServletContextListener` here [link](http://www.deadcoderising.com/execute-code-on-webapp-startup-and-shutdown-using-servletcontextlistener/).

As long your thread isn't IO related then you can just set it to daemon to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat does not stop any threads that it did not start.

So, Tomcat will shut-down its own thread-pools, but if your application started threads, those will continue to execute after Tomcat shuts itself down.

If those threads are "daemon" threads, then the JVM will stop them when the `main` thread (which is the thread that starts Tomcat if you are using a standard startup-mode – no embedding, etc.) stops.

You should always arrange to have your application shut-down its own threads. As @MichealDz suggests, the best way is to use a `ServletContextListener`.