# ExecutorService not shutting down after Tomcat shutdown

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, stomp

Thanks for this opportunity to ask questions here.

**Summary**

I have a spring boot application which runs on Tomcat. I'm subscribing ActiveMQ topic with StompClient. After connected i get messages via StompHandler's handleFrame method.
In that method i create MessageUtils which implements Runnable interface. In MessageUtils run method, creating new thread with ExecutorService and do the task generateMessage which send messages to kafka topic.

**Problem**

When I shutdown the tomcat, threads are still alive. In catalina.out;

`A web application appears to have started a thread named [foo] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak`

So the tomcat cannot shutdown properly.

**Code Samples**

@Service

StompService.class

```
@EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void start() {

        logI("Service run Client Methods");
        List<String> topics = Arrays.asList(topicListString.split(","));
        for (String topic : topics) {
            StompClient client = new StompClient(topic, username, password, url, topic, bootstrapAddress);
            try {
                client.run();
                runMap.put(topic, client);
                boolean connected = client.getSession().isConnected();
                logI("Topic: " + topic + " is connected: " + connected);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                logE("InterruptedException during start of stomp client: ", e);
            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
                logE("TimeoutException during start of stomp client: ", e);
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                logE("ExecutionException during start of stomp client: ", e);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logE("Unexpected exception during start of stomp client: ", e);
            }
        }

    }
```

StompClient.class

```
public void run() throws ExecutionException, TimeoutException, InterruptedException {

        WebSocketClient client = new StandardWebSocketClient();

        WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(client);

        ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
        taskScheduler.afterPropertiesSet();

        StompHeaders connectHeaders = new StompHeaders();
        connectHeaders.add("login", this.userName);
        connectHeaders.add("passcode", this.password);


        stompClient.getDefaultHeartbeat();
        stompClient.setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler);
        stompClient.setMessageConverter(new StringMessageConverter());
        stompClient.setAutoStartup(true);
        StompSessionHandler sessionHandler = new StompHandler(this.topic, this.bootstrapAddress);
        StompSession stompSession = null;
        try {
            stompSession = stompClient.connect(url, new WebSocketHttpHeaders(), connectHeaders, sessionHandler)
                    .get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logE("Cannot connect with stomp client." , e);
        }


        this.setSession(stompSession);

    }
```

StompHandler.class which extends StompSessionHandlerAdapter

```
@Override
    public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {

        String msg = (String) payload;

        MessageUtils message = new MessageUtils();
        message.setHeaders(headers);
        message.setTopic(topic);
        message.setMsg(msg);
        message.setBootstrapAddress(bootstrapAddress);
        message.run();

    }
```

MessageUtils.class

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                    generateMessage(getMsg().toString());
            }

        });
        executorService.shutdown();
        try {
            executorService.awaitTermination(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logI("InterruptedException during await termination", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: [maybe related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49145238/does-tomcat-wait-for-application-threads-to-complete-before-shutdown). Also - are you using spring boot and deploying it it standalone tomcat? Also from the code it seems that you create executorservice instance per handleFrame method? That might be wasteful.

Comment: @MichałKrzywański I'll check the ServletContextListener. Can that do kill all threads started by the application or Should i put the threads somewhere and get all into the ServletContextListener? And yes i'm using spring boot deploying to Tomcat on a Linux machine. If you can advice better way i can look at it.

Comment: I would not create the executor service for every message but only once and use for example cached pool - but it depends on your use case. And then in `ServletContextListener` shutdown the pool. Also I do not know that `generateMessage` method does so `shutdownNow` might also be needed. Check how to properly close the pool in [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

Comment: Creating an executor makes sense only if you submit more than one task to it - i.e. if you reuse it. Having an executor without re-using just complicates things: if you really want to start a thread per message (a design that I think rarely makes sense), just create a new Thread, passing a runnable and call start, when the runnable terminates the thread has terminated - no shutdown logic required. If you don't want the JVM to hang on a non-terminated thread when shutting down you need to set its daemon flag.

Comment: @MichałKrzywański thanks for your infomation. I just removed thread parts, implemented the ServletContextListener and stopped the stomp sessions. When i tried the stop tomcat it still warns about somethings are still open. After that application hit the contextDestroyed method and killed all the sessions. Then application closed successfully. Your comment kinda be the solution. If you can write it as an answer so i can mark.